# Getting JSON result after POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm currently trying to `POST` a Submit form with an input for search and get the results via `JSON`. All project is a Web App that search in some XMLs files for get the POST results.

My form in my index.html starts like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/results">
```

**/results is the page where are JSON results in plain text.**

In other hand, in my script I am trying to get JSON results like this:

```
$("#buttonid").on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/results',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $(data).each(function(index,value){
                console.log(value);

            });
        }
    });
};
```

I can't see the results by console. What can I do? Any advice for solve my problem?

**Edited:**

Isn't only a simple typographical error, I solved the issue deleting `action="/results"` in my form and adding `data: $(this).serialize(),` in ajax options. Thanks to @foxygen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Amir said, `success` is spelled wrong. But I'm adding three things that will help you further. Since you are POSTing data, you need to add the form data to the `data` property when passing your options to the `ajax` function. Also, it's common practice to add the `error` callback as well. Finally - you should call `preventDefault` on the event so that the page doesn't reload.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url:'/results',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){

            $(data).each(function(index,value){

                console.log(value);

            });
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: And maybe buttonid is a submit button which then will post the FORM and so redirect page

Comment: @A.Wolff - good point. See my update

Comment: Hi, thanks at all for you help but I cannot solve the problem yet. Now Google Chrome console trough that error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (anonymous function)` in first line in `$("buttonid")...`
I checked but the _button id_ is correct. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes is a submit button but I would like don't reload the page. How can I do? I'm newbie :|

Comment: @A.Wolff Is it possible delete `action="/results"` and do the same as I want? What do you think?

Comment: Important don't forget the '#' before form id. I spent so much time to see it :(
And @foxygen, the page still refresh when submit. Is it possible to avoid refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo(`success` and not `succes`):

```
$("#buttonid").on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/results',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $(data).each(function(index,value){
                console.log(value);

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `the page where are JSON results in plain text` but OP set `dataType: 'json'`, this would throw error client side, i guess...